# Operation `.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms - Node.js Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to send recipe data such as title, description,prep time etc, but i keep getting this error Operation `recipes.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms. I have tried almost every solution i have stumbled across but I still get this error. I have an auth service that works but this is the only part that doesnt want to work atm. Heres the core:

**Recipe Controller**

```js
const Recipes = require('../models/recipe')

const post = (req, res) => {
  const recipe = new Recipes(req.body);
  console.log(recipe)
  recipe.save();
  try {
    res.status(201).send({
      message: 'Recipe posted'
    })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send({
      err: console.error(),
      message: `${err}`
    })
  }
}

module.exports = {
  post
}
```

**Recipe Model**

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const recipeSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    title: {
        type: String,
        required: ["Must Have Title"]
    },
    category: {
        type: String,
        required: ['Must have selected a Category']
    },
    prepTime: {
        type: Number,
        required: ['Must have a Prep Time'],
    },
    numberOfPeople: {
        type: Number,
        required: ['Must have a number of people'],
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: ['Must have a description']
    }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Recipes', recipeSchema, 'recipes')
```

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let DSN = `mongodb://localhost:27017/recipes`;

mongoose.connect(
  DSN,
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  }, err => {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('Could not connect to DB: ', err);
    }
    console.log('Successfully connected to database...');
  });
```

Edit:

console.log(req.body) shows the information I want to post, chances are it is a connection error when using the create or new functions. My log in and register posts work and post and pull from the database so there's something specifically wrong with either with the schema or the way the files are connected to mongodb

Edit no.2:

It apparently has nothing to do with the code inside the controller, tried it with the auth schema same code and all and i got the same error. So chances are its something else

Edit no.3 aka the end:

I had forgotten to connect the config file with the index.js, I am an idiot

Comment: Is the connection to the database actually successfuil?

Comment: Can you `console.log(req.body)` inside `post` function and add it to the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
const post = async(req, res) => {
  try {
    const recipe = await Recipes.create(req.body);
    res.status(201).send({ message: 'Recipe posted' })
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).send({err: console.error(), message: `${err}` })
  }
}
```

Comment: Sadly didn't work, console.log(req.body) showed the info being taken from postman...it just doesn't want to be stored in the db

Answer (score 0):

There is likely an error with your connection. Mongo does not wait to establish a connection before letting you start using your models, buffering into infinity until the connection can actually function.

Try one of the following, based on what you're able to change:

```
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/recipes/test?connectTimeoutMS=1000&bufferCommands=false&authSource=otherdb');

// The above is equivalent to:
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/recipes', {
  connectTimeoutMS: 1000
  // Note that mongoose will **not** pull `bufferCommands` from the query string
});
```

Your `console.log('Could not connect to DB: ', err);` would essentially never fire otherwise, unless the connection was immediately rejected, based on the drivers behavior.

Further source material is available in the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#connections).